# Adding fields to trailler alters checksum position - quickfix C# - #quickfixn

Tags: quickfixn

my friends.

I am trying to update these two trailer fields using this code below, but, each time I do it, they go past checksum invalidating so the resulting message.

--------------------------code -----------------

```
        no.Trailer.SetField(new Signature("CHAVE"));
        no.Trailer.SetField(new SignatureLength(5));
```

---

resulting message:

..... 10=153 89=CHAVE 93=5

What should be the right way to get them edited?

If I use just, "no.SetField" it gives me a "Tag specified out of required order" message.

Thanks in advance,
Roberto.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but, compiling and using the QuickFix44.DLL from the github most recent code solved the problem.

Thanks.